# Lotus Notes Sending email with options

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm using Lotus Domino.dll. Already finished sending. How set delivery options to `DeliveryPriority=H` and `DeliveryReport=C`?
CODE

```
NotesSession _notesSession = new NotesSession();
NotesDocument _notesDocument = null;
string sMailFile = "mail/" + login + ".nsf";
 _notesSession.Initialize(passwrod);
 NotesDatabase _notesDataBase = _notesSession.GetDatabase(sServerName, sMailFile, false);
            if (!_notesDataBase.IsOpen)
            {
                _notesDataBase.Open();
            }
            _notesDocument = _notesDataBase.CreateDocument();
            _notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
            _notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", aSendTo);
            _notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", aSubject);
            NotesRichTextItem _richTextItem = _notesDocument.CreateRichTextItem("Body");
            _richTextItem.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
 _richTextItem.EmbedObject(EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", file);
 var oItemValue = _notesDocument.GetItemValue("SendTo");
 _notesDocument.SaveMessageOnSend = true;
 _notesDocument.Send(false, ref oItemValue);
```

Comment: Please show the code you're currently using to create and send the email.

Comment: Scott Leis, code added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the lines

```
        _notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("DeliveryPriority", "H");
        _notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("DeliveryReport", "C");
```

after your Subject line.

You can find a complete list of mail options [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_FIELDS_THAT_CONTROL_MAILING_OPTIONS.html).