# Connection to Domino crashes

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I'm trying to send an email using a Domino server from C#/VB.NET. (Having Lotus Notes client 8.5.3FP6)

The code looks like

```
using Domino;
...
try 
{
    NotesSession ns = new NotesSession();
    NotesDatabase db = default(NotesDatabase);
    NotesDocument doc = default(NotesDocument);
    if (ns != null)
    {
        ns.Initialize(password); // Crashes here
...
```

I've looked at several example like

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29442/Send-Lotus-Notes-Email-Using-C

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/628681/Sending-mail-from-LotusNotes-using-Csharp

[Lotus Notes Sending email with options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448948/lotus-notes-sending-email-with-options)

but they all crash in the Initialize call, without coming to the catch statement so I can see any error message.

What can be wrong? I have tried InitializeUsingNotesUserName as well as not sending in the password to Initialize, with same results.

I've also tried to import the reference to Domino if there was any problem with the interop file.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building for 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: Okay, that's good - because the Domino COM classes are not supported for 64 bits. And you're saying the catch statement isn't getting invoked at all? Is an nsd file being created in the IBM Technical Support folder within the Notes client installation?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following setting and see if it helps, can be found in File -> Security - User Security in Notes client

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I ended up using the SMTP server instead. Seemed much more easy and stable..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your "DB" where you try to create a mail, but when I try to send a mail directly via Lotus Notes I use a selfmade function which directly create the mail into the server based mail.box

The reason why I do that is, that I have seen issues, when multiple users shared the same PC (and where they have only read access to the names.nsf or a local mail.box). I never saw that a client crash, but the issue with missing rights often caused similar error messages (Please not that IBM didn´t really support using the same profile for multiple users, so this is more the users fault because they didn´t the time it takes to relogin via windows). Since using the mail.box I haven´t seen such issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had crashes when calling 'new NotesSession()', and solved it by registering nlsxbe.dll (run as administrator):

```
> regsvr32 "c:\program files(x86)\ibm\notes\nlsxbe.dll"
```